# How to find labels for a folder and it's files/subfolders

Tags: clearcase

I assume there's no built in solution.
I'm using `cleartool descr -fmt "%l\n" path` to find labels for a particular directory, but it doesn't include subfolders.

Is there any way to find labels for a folder and all of it's childs?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to find all the versions you want (the version of the folder selected by your config spec, as well as the version of the files and subfolders)

That would be with [`cleartool find`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm).
You can combine [`cleartool describe`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm) and find with the `-exec` directive and is [`fmt_ccase` syntax](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm):

```
cleartool find . -exec "cleartool describe -fmt \"%n %l\n\" \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""
```

Comment: Hi @VonC. I'm not sure why but that command cycles indefinitely. It never exits and prints out label names (not sure yet if they are correct, will have to check on that). Also %CLEARCASE_PN% should be replaced with folder path right?

Comment: @Davita  `%CLEARCASE_PN%` is correct. The `cleartool find` can be fairly long. You can go in a subfolder of the vob/view first, and do your `cleartool find .` there, just to check that it does print the version it finds. Then add the `-exec` part. Again, do that in the subfolder, to limit the search.

Comment: Hi @VonC. Thanks again for quick reply. Yes I'm trying from one subfolder. cleartool find . -print works fine. It displays versions in few seconds and exits, while whole command cleartool find . -exec "cleartool describe -fmt \"%n %l\n\" \"%.\"" <-- never exits

Comment: @Davita What is your ClearCase version and your current shell? (a CMD on Windows?)